# Relation Between $Y, K, \eta$ and $\sigma$

Tags: material-science, solid-mechanics

How did we get the following relations between $Y, K, \eta$ and $\sigma$, where $Y$ is [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus), $K$ is [Bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus), $\eta$ is [Shear modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus), and $\sigma$ is [Poisson's ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio)? (*Some books and Wikipedia use* $Y$, $B$, $G$, *and* $\nu$ *instead*.)

(i) $Y=3 K(1-2 \sigma)$ or $Y=3 B(1-2 \nu)$

(ii) $Y=2 \eta(1+\sigma)$ or $Y=2 G(1+\nu)$

(iii) $\sigma=\frac{3 K-2 \eta}{2 \eta+6 K}$ or $\nu=\frac{3 B-2 G}{6 B+2 G}$

(iv) $\frac{9}{Y}=\frac{1}{K}+\frac{3}{\eta}$ or $Y=\frac{9 K \eta}{\eta+3 K}$ or $Y=\frac{9 B G}{3 B+G}$

Comment: [Derivation from first principles of linear elasticity](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/generalized%20Hooke's%20Law.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note (iii) and (iv) are simple consequences of (i) and (ii). They are obtained by solving the linear system for $\nu$ and $E$ (Young's modulus), respectively.

To derive (i), consider a cube with perpendicular stresses $\sigma$ on all faces. The cube strains on each direction by $\epsilon$. We'll calculate this in two ways.

By normal stress, they stretch according to $E$ and $\nu$ as (the direct result of the normal, minus the squeezing due to Poisson's ratio)

$$\epsilon=\frac{\sigma}{E}-\nu\frac{\sigma}{E}-\nu\frac{\sigma}{E}=(1-2\nu)\frac{\sigma}{E}.$$

But by volumetric stress, it stretches according to $\kappa$ (bulk modulus) by (cubing the displacements)

$$3\epsilon=\frac{\sigma}{\kappa}.$$

Putting these together, we get (i)

$$E=3\kappa(1-2\nu).$$

Now, deriving (ii) is a bit more complicated. Consider a cube with one of its faces fixed to the floor. From the side it's going to look like a square, $ABCD$, with $AB$ touching the ground  Apply a shear stress $\sigma$ along $DC$. This displaces $D\rightarrow D'$ and $C\rightarrow C'$, with strain computing with shear modulus $\mu$ we get

$$\epsilon=\sigma/\mu=DD'/AD=CC'/BC.$$

However, we're effetively applying (decomposing the stress) $\sigma$ along both $DB$, as a compression, and $AC$, as a tension. Let's look at it from this perspective and write $\epsilon$ using $E,\nu$. Again, direct stress along $AC$ minus ratio'd along $DB$:

$$\frac{AC'-AC}{AC}=\frac{CC'/\sqrt2}{BC\sqrt2}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\frac{\sigma}{E}-\nu\left(-\frac{\sigma}{E}\right),$$
$$\epsilon=(1+\nu)\frac{\sigma}{E}.$$

We combine these two equations to get (ii):

$$E=2\mu(1+\nu).$$